# Spawn a Shell By Tagging Onto An Existing Command Run As Sudo

Tags: bash

Is there a way to do the below and spawn the second command as root?

```
 sudo whatever && /bin/sh
```

I tried it with the below but it still puts me as the original user.

```
sudo who && /bin/sh
```

I want to know if you can spawn a shell via running a second command once sudo was invoked ONCE.  This is important, as I can't run a command like `sudo x && sudo y` for the testing I'm trying to create regarding (what I believe) is vulnerable coding in an app that (in the backend) executes a program as `sudo`.  I just need to try and tag a command on the front of it to see if I can immediately just spawn a root shell.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
sudo bash -c 'date && sleep 2 && echo $USER && date'
```

Note the `$USER` must be single-quoted to ensure it is evaluated within the sudo bash. If it is double-quoted, it gets evaluated by the regular user's bash ***before*** the sudo is actioned.